# Сортировка по возрастанию и убыванию Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Есть модель Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)
    price = models.CharField(verbose_name='price', db_index=True, max_length=64)
    isFan = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_auth_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favorite_posts')
    likes = GenericRelation(Like)
    objects = PostManager()
```

Мне необходимо отсортировать по created и по price:

created - по возрастанию и по убыванию
price - по возрастанию и по убыванию.

Выбрать вариант сортировки, естественно, можно только один.
Сейчас во ViewSet'е сортируется только по убыванию даты(от новых к старым).

```
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.is_actual().order_by('-created')
```

Как реализовать выше указананную сортировку?

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что можно только одно поле использовать в `order_by`? Просто добавьте вторым параметром `price`.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, как изменить тогда вариант сортивки? От большего к меньшему, либо от меньшего к большему?

Comment: Пока не попробуешь - не узнаешь.